# Is there a way to use predict to predict a change in values?

Tags: r, predict

```
days <- c(21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42)
area <- c(18.4, 19.5, 21.3, 21.5, 23.2, 23.8, 24.7, 26)
q1 <- data.frame(days, area)

regressq1 <- lm(area~days,data=q1)

predb <- data.frame(days=10)
predict(regressq1, newdata = predb, interval = "confidence")
```

So from my understanding, the above code predicts what the value of area would be when the value of days is 10, and gives me the corresponding 95% confidence interval. What I would like to do is generate some code that tells me what the CHANGE in area would be over 10 days, and generate corresponding 95% confidence intervals. I can do this by hand but I was wondering if there was some feature of predict() that would do this in R that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a linear model, the coefficient of variable "days" in `summary(regressq1)` would give you the point estimator and CI of "the CHANGE in area over 1 day". 
A way to get the point estimator and CI of "the CHANGE in area over 10 day" is:

```
days <- c(21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42)/10
area <- c(18.4, 19.5, 21.3, 21.5, 23.2, 23.8, 24.7, 26)
q1 <- data.frame(days, area)

regressq1 <- lm(area~days,data=q1)

summary(regressq1)
```

This time, the coefficient of the variable "days" would be the point estimator of the change in area over 10 days. and point estimator plus\minus 1.96*SE is the CI for the change.